# Wrong Multicast MAC address with more than one network interface

Tags: linux, redhat, multicast

I am trying to subscribe to a multicast group from a Red Hat machine with four network interfaces, each one is on a different subnet. It only works if I bind the multicast socket on the network interface on which the gateway matches with the configured default gateway.

My route table (output of "route" command):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.37.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.1.39.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
10.1.38.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.1.33.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth3
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 eth2
default         10.1.33.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Each subnet has a firewall configured as gateway (on each ifcfg-ethX configuration file), in all interfaces it has the *.1 address on that subnet.

Here is my research using Wireshark:

If I bind the socket on eth0, the operating system sends the multicast join packet with the Dst field on the Ethernet layer set to 01:00:5e:02:02:11, a multicast MAC address. The firewall accepts that packet and starts relaying packets for that multicast group.

If I bind the socket on eth2, the operating system sends the multicast join packet with the Dst field on the Ethernet layer set to 84:b8:02:d2:cd:88, the physical MAC address of the firewall. The firewall discards that packet as it does not have a valid multicast MAC address.

If I change the default gateway to 10.1.37.1, then the multicast starts working on eth2 but not in eth0.

Is there any wrong configuration that I have? Is there any way to get different multicast groups working on different network interfaces at the same time?

Comment: What's the multicast application?

Comment: It's a C++ application, compiled and linked on the same machine that it is running. I've tried also with a Java application, and I got the same behaviour.

Comment: I suspected that. I'd say you'll have better luck posting on StackOverflow and showing your code. Are you setting the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` socket option?

Comment: I posted this on StackOverflow and got a comment saying that I would flag it to ask a moderator to move it here. I flagged it and nobody moved that, so I deleted the Q on StackOverflow. And yes, I tried the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` socket option.

Comment: Have you set all the appropriate mcast forwarding variables in /etc/sysctl.conf.   Specific OS distro and version please.  Also you might need to install a multicast routing software on your RHEL host like pimd?

Comment: I've tested this on RHEL Server 6.2, RHEL Server 6.5, RHEL Server 7.0, RHEL Workstation 6.4 and RHEL Workstation 7.0. It happens in all of them. Also, sysctl.conf is correctly configured, and iptables is disabled.